# How to paste two vectors together and pad at the end?

Tags: string, r, paste

I would like to `paste` two character strings together and pad at the end with another character to make the combination a certain length.  I was wondering if there was an option to `paste` that one can pass or another trick that I am missing? I can do this in multiple lines by figuring out the length of each and then calling `paste` with `rep(my_pad_character,N)` but I would like to do this in one line.

Ex: pad together `"hi"`, and `"hello"` and pad with an `"a"` to make the sequence length 10. the result would be `"hihelloaaa"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `stringr` function `str_pad`

```
library(stringr)
str_pad(paste0('hi','hello'), side = 'right', width = 10 , pad = 'a')
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is one option:

```
s1 <- "hi"
s2 <- "hello"

f <- function(x, y, pad = "a", length = 10) {
   out <- paste0(x, y)
   nc <- nchar(out)
   paste0(out, paste(rep(pad, length - nc), collapse = ""))
}

> f(s1, s2)
[1] "hihelloaaa"
```

Comment: You could replace `x` and `y` with `...`

Comment: this is actually what i ended up coding up, i was hoping to use a built in function just so i don't have to keep sourcing this

Comment: @Alex this is where a personal package comes in useful (you don't have to write the Rd files if you don't want!). Then just load your package of functions as you need them. Just like you would with `stringr` in mnel's Answer.

Comment: @GavinSimpson: interesting! I haven't looked into this because sourcing just seems very fast and creating a package might take a bit of work. Is that right or it's not that bad?

Comment: It isn't much work, you don't need to write Rd files, just list them all as alias on one Rd file. You may need the package build tools, which may be more or less involved depending on your OS.